# What topologies are placed on the domain and range of the characteristic function?

Tags: general-topology, characteristic-functions, convention

under consideration is: $\mathbb{1}_{[0,1)}:\mathbb{R}\to\{0,1\}$
$$\mathbb{1}_{[0,1)}(x)=
\begin{cases}
1,& 0\leq x<1\\
0,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
My first question is that I don't know what the 'default' topology on $\{0,1\}$ is? Is it the discrete topology, or the Sierpiński topology?

My second question is most clearly formulated in general terms first:

If $f:X\to Y$ a map between topological space, then what topology is implicitly used on $A$ in the restriction $f|A:A\to Y$?

Specifically in this example we consider $\mathbb{1}_{[0,1)}\lvert{[0,1]}:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}$. Then what is the topology defined on $[0,1]$? I suspect it is the subspace topology, so that $[0,0.1)$ for example is open.

Comment: In what context?  The 'default' topology on $\{0, 1\}$ is almost always the discrete topology, but it might still be a matter of context.  

In general, though, you can assume that $\{0,1\}$ is a shorthand for '$\{0, 1\}$ with the discrete topology'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default topology on $\{0,1\}$ is the subspace topology induced from $\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$, i.e. the discrete topology. If a different topology is considered, that is (usually, at least) explicitly mentioned. Typically, characteristic functions are considered in contexts where other real- or complex-valued functions occur too, and one adds or multiplies these functions, so one considers characteristic functions as real- or complex-valued, only the range happens to be contained in $\{0,1\}$.

For the second question, when considering the restriction of a map $f\colon X \to Y$ between two topological spaces to $A\subset X$, the topology on $A$ one considers is, unless explicitly stated otherwise, the subspace topology on $A$ induced by $X$.

Comment: Oke, both are as I would have expected, but I just wanted to be sure (since this was never made explicit in the book I'm reading). Thanks